# CSS and JS - trying to get "livesearch" results appear as a floating dropdown instead of pushing away content around it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using W3CSS along with some JavaScript to have a livesearch bar at the top of my website - I need the search bar to display results as the user types - however I need the results to display on top of other content. Right now they are pushing other content around and I am not sure how to stop that. As I mentioned I am using W3CSS and I tried setting the div containing my results to use class='w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block' but then the results are completely invisible. Help would be much appreciated!

Here is my HTML

```html
<!-- NAV HEADER -->
<div class='w3-top'>
    <div class='w3-bar w3-light-grey'>
        <a href='home.php' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><i class='material-icons'>home</i></a> 
        <a href='view_customer.php' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'>Customers</a>
        <a href='tickets.php' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'>Tickets</a>
        <a href='info.php' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'>Info</a>
        <a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'>Reports</a>
        <input type='text' class='w3-bar-item w3-input' placeholder='Search..' onkeyup='showResult(this.value)'>
        <div id='livesearch'></div>
        <a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><i class='material-icons'>calendar_today</i></a>
        <a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><i class='material-icons'>settings</i></a>
        <a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><i class='material-icons'>notifications_none</i></a>
        <a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><i class='material-icons'>person</i>Employee Name \/</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```js
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look you are just putting the response in the code which 1 does nothing and 2 try using fetch method like so

```
    function showResult(str) {
            fetch("livesearch.php?q="+str)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(function(response){
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML= response;
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
            });
        }
```

This is a smaller version of your code and this should work like a charm

Comment: While I appreciate your response, that part is working fine. When inspecting the code with Chrome I can see the div is populated with my results and they appear on the page. The issue is that I need them to appear floating above the rest of the page content, not pushing them out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be one solution:

```
(...) 
<a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'>Reports</a>
<div class='w3-dropdown w3-bar-item'>
     <input type='text' class=' w3-input' placeholder='Search..' onkeyup='showResult(this.value)'>
     <div id='livesearch' class="w3-border w3-dropdown-content "></div>
</div>  
<a href='#' class='w3-bar-item w3-button'><i class='material-icons'>calendar_today</i></a>
(...)
```

In order to show the dropdwon your function must add the class "w3-show" to the div "livesearch" and remove this class when you want hide it.